# How to parse menu links

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul li a').click(function(){
    $('li a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
});
```

```css
.header-menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}

.header-menu ul li a.active {
      color: #c58a52;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="header-menu">
                    <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">profile</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
       </nav>
```

How to parse menu links so that the active menu item is highlighted when the page is navigated / updated? The example code works here, but if you refresh or navigate to another page, then the style is reset. Perhaps there are other options?

Answer (score 0):

What i added:

1. modified the href's to contain a hash
2. on page load, check the hash and set the active link by the hash

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  $('ul li a[href="#' + hash + '"]').addClass('active');
  $('ul li a').click(function() {
    $('li a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.header-menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.header-menu ul li a.active {
  color: #c58a52;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="header-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#services">services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile">profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#blog">blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: How does it  works with real links? I get "#" in url address

Comment: with real links, you would have to check the URL and change the code accordingly. something like `var segments = window.location.href.split( '/' );` and take the last part of the segments and compare it.

Comment: This code doesn`t work correctly. The loop and condition are missing here. The class  ".active " should be added only to the link that is active.